# Arduino Rotary Encoder Pulses?

Tags: rotary-encoder

I made an program so if I turn on my rotary encoder the position and the rotation comes on a LCD screen. But I need to change it a bit up for my teacher, she wants to see the graph of the pulses on the serial monitor. I searched it up and can't find a solution? Any help?

My program:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> 
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2); 
#define outputA 2 
#define outputB 4 
int counter = 0; 
int angle = 0; 
int aState; 
int aLastState; 
int lastAngle = 0; 
String rotationDirection; 
String savedRotationDirection;

void setup() {
  pinMode (outputA,INPUT);
  pinMode (outputB,INPUT);

  aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
  lcd.begin();


     } 

void loop() {
  aState = digitalRead(outputA);
  if (aState != aLastState){     
     if (digitalRead(outputB) != aState) { 
       counter ++;
       angle ++;
     }
     else {
       counter--;
       angle --;
     }
     if (counter >=30 ) {
      counter = 0;
     } 

     if (angle < lastAngle){
      rotationDirection = "CCW";
     }
     else {
      if (angle > lastAngle){
        rotationDirection = "CW";
      }
      else {
        rotationDirection = savedRotationDirection;
      }
     }
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.setCursor(0,0);
     lcd.print("Position: ");
     lcd.print(int(angle)*(-1));
     lcd.print((char)223); 
     lcd.setCursor(0,1);
     lcd.print("Rotation: ");
     lcd.print(rotationDirection);
     savedRotationDirection = rotationDirection;
     lastAngle = angle;
  }
  aLastState = aState;

}
```

Comment: `My program:`  is hard to read formatted like that

Comment: almost every Arduino example uses prints to Serial Monitor

Comment: `I searched it up` ... what did you search for?

Comment: Just a few comments on your code: 1. You can remove `counter`, as you never use it. 2. `aState` and `rotationDirection` should be local variables. 3. `savedRotationDirection` serves no useful purpose: you can just remove every line in which it appears. 4. `lastAngle` is not useful either: you know the angle increases when you do `angle++`, and it decreases when you do `angle--`.

Answer (score 2):

Add Serial.begin(115200); in setup() and use Serial.println() or Serial.print() to print to Serial.

In Arduino IDE open Serial Monitor and set baud rate to 115200.

EDIT: The question turned out to be about Serial Plotter. Maximilian Gerhardt answered in a comment :

> If you want multiple data streams (graphs) you need to seperate them
>   by a comma: Serial.println( String(digitalRead(outputA)) + "," +
>   String(digitalRead(outputB)));

Comment: Nothing's happening. My question is how to see the graph of the pulse in the serial monitor?

Comment: Serial Plotter in IDE?

Comment: Used it but still nothing happens.

Comment: Used this: 
Serial.println(digitalRead(outputA));
Serial.println(digitalRead(outputB)); 
Now I only get one of the 2. Is there a way to get both but under eachother?

Comment: If you want multiple data streams (graphs) you need to seperate them by a comma: `Serial.println( String(digitalRead(outputA)) + "," + String(digitalRead(outputB)));` (https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2016/01/tutorial-multiple-values-in-the-arduino-ide-serial-plotter/) @user43154

Comment: Yes, that worked thanks. Further information I'll search first by myself. Thanks!